# How to get parameters from root function

Tags: python, flask

I have the code below:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<param1>", methods=["GET"])
def func1(param1):
    return func2()

def func2():
    return "mystring"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
```

The question is how to pass `param1` to `func2` but not as a function parameter. In my project `func2()` is in another module and I have a lot of parameters in my URL. Can I have access to `param1` from `func2` for example via `flask.request` or something like this?

Yes I know that i can put all necessary parameters into a dictionary and pass this dictionary to `func2` and to another function, but I would like to know if there is another way to access url-parameters.

Comment: May look into [current_app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.current_app). But I think it's not a natural requirement. Just pass it as a parameter and my use default `=None` so you can call it without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask provides a variable [`g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/) that exists for the lifetime of the request. Depending on your situation, this may be an appropriate use for it.

To use it, import it:

```
from flask import g
```

In your example:

```
@app.route("/<param1>", methods=["GET"])
def func1(param1):
    g.info = "Hello world"
    return func2()

def func2():
    if g.info == "Hello world":
        return "Hello world"
    return "mystring"
```

Note: This variable is automatically available to the template, which may not be desirable.